# Floating on both sides separately without interfering

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like to decorate and shape the left and right borders of my text using float and clear properties. To start I have this markup which looks like the left and right stair steps should both start at the top of the page. However, the stairs aren't vertically aligned; the second stairs seem to always start drawing at the second-to-last step on the other side.

```html
<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left</div>
<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left Two</div>
<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left Number Three</div>

<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right Two</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right Number Three</div>

... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... .
```

The result (same in Chrome + Firefox):

[image]

I'd like the stairs to both start at the beginning, as they seem like they should, since I'm only clearing floats on the side they're on. Note that I'm not just shaping the borders, I'm also showing important things on the shaped sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easyest way to solve the problem,
just to change places the rows like this:
green, red, green, red, green, red.
This code works properly:

```
<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right</div>
<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left Two</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right Two</div>
<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left Number Three</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right Number Three</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A floated element isn't positioned independently of the document flow - it's vertically placed wherever the preceding element is (be it a block, floated or not, or inline content) - in the flow of elements inside the document.

So what you are looking for (floated elements with content floating around it, but independently left and right independent from the document flow) is basically impossible.

EDIT:

Here's the code from the comment below, with some longer text in it to show what I mean:

```css
div,
p {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right</div>
<p>Some text in between</p>
<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left Two</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right Two</div>
<p>Some more text in between. Some more text in between,  in between,  in between. Some more text in between. </p>
<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left Number Three</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right Number Three</div>
<p>And again less text in between.</p>
```

So a workaround like that can only work with a very little amount of content/text (or none) in between. (Note also that I set the `p`'s `margin`s to `0`, otherwise there would be whitespace between the "steps".)

Comment: Intermixing the stairs works, so it's not impossible.
```
<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right</div>

<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left Two</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right Two</div>

<div style="float: left; clear: left; background: green;">Left Number Three</div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right; background: red;">Right Number Three</div>
```

Comment: I wrote `independent from the document flow` and `with content floating around it` - I guess that's what you want. Your example only works with those very short texts in between as long as they fit between two floated elements, and only if any two floated elements which are on the same line have exactly the same height. As soon as any text is long enough to flow into the next line, this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: "Impossible" is just a cliché. It doesn't work in my sample code, obviously. I continued to hack on it and found a very simple CSS-only solution already.

Comment: Apparently if you just shuffle the order of the floats so that the next one is always placed on the shorter side, you get the desired result. That's enough for what I'm planning.

Answer (score 0):

You could fake this with clearing the `float` on the 3 last items and use `direction` to get the right alignement for the last 3 items too.

example from a list:

```css
/* required */

.stairCcase {
  direction: rtl;
}

.stairCcase li {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  direction: ltr;
}

.stairCcase :nth-child(3)~li {
  float: none;
  clear: none;
  display: table; /* or width:max-content instead display */
}


/* reset & styles for demo*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  width: 10em;
  margin: auto;
}

li {
  background: green;
  padding:0.25em;
}

li:nth-child(3)~li {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="stairCcase">
  <li>0 </li>
  <li>0 0 </li>
  <li> 0 0 0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1 1</li>
  <li>1 1 1</li>
</ul>
```

a few ressources about `float` : https://css-tricks.com/?s=float&orderby=relevance&post_type=post%2Cpage%2Cguide & `direction` https://css-tricks.com/?s=direction&orderby=relevance&post_type=post%2Cpage%2Cguide

---

**for such a layout, you should consider using the grid `display`.**

Example below

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "left    .     .   .   .      .    right " 
  "left2 left2   .   .   .    right2 right2" 
  "left3 left3 left3 . right3 right3 right3"
}

li {
  grid-area: left;
  border:solid;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: left2
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: left3
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: right
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: right2
}

li:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: right3
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  counter-reset: lis
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: lis;
  content: counter(lis);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-template-areas